# Multiple wsgi py files

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I received a project developed by other person and I noticed three wsgi.py files. how do I identify which is the principal?

I have django_wsgi.py, uwsgi.py, project_wsgi.py

Thank you

Comment: How is the application hosted and which of the files does the configuration of the hosting mechanism refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that *other person* is indisposed, that s/he wrote no documentation, and that nobody else knows anything about it. Based on their names, it looks as if one is designed to be used with [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and another with [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/). As for the third, I'm unfamiliar with any wsgi implementation called *project*, so I can only conjecture, but I'd say *all three* are the principal: One if you're using django, another for uwsgi and another for… I dunno, development?